# expo-image-picker android error with content:// uri

Tags: android, expo, eas, expo-image-picker

Installed `expo-image-picker`, calling `launchImageLibraryAsync`. This works completely fine on Emulator.

On a real android device (Samsung A3, API 24), and picking images from the Library, I sometimes get an error `Uri lacks 'file' scheme: content://com.android.provider.media.documents/documents/<imagename..>`.

My understanding is that it's images which have been saved NOT by the device camera, e.g. whatsapp, other apps using the camera. Images which were taken on the device camera work OK  and have a local path.

Is there a known way to deal with this? I can't seem to stop the user seeing/picking these images, and can't pass in any options to ignore this error (or fail gracefully if multiple images are selected and only 1 fails). Currently we just catch and give a generic error which is a bit mmm.

Answer (score 1):

I've reported this issue in the proper Github repository.
Take a look in order to get an answer.

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/24172

PS.: At the moment I'm writing this, there is no answer. That's why I'm pasting the link here.

Comment: There is a fix available, waiting for publication at the moment

Comment: @TeChn4K which is the published version that fixes this?

Comment: expo-image-picker@14.5.0 works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend that you do not use the Debugger while doing this. Maybe because of the URI it can cause problems.

The library you need for FileSystem: `expo-file-system`

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'
let uri = ''
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  const path = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(result.uri)
  uri = path.uri
} else {
  uri = result.uri.replace('file:///', '/')
}

const file = {
  uri,
  type: 'image/jpg',
  name: result?.uri?.split('/').pop()
}
```